# Missing Collation for MySQL tables with MySQL 8, phpmyadmin 5.2, and php8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I just updated my server software to the latest versions: apache 2.4.54, MySQL8, phpmyadmin 5.2 and php8.1. MySQL initialized the new server and database without errors.

Some of my tables in MySQL databases (from the prior version of MySQL and phpmyadmin) are now showing three dashes, " --- ",  instead of the selected collation. After reviewing my old MySQL records, I see the missing collation is utf8_general_ci.

I changed the default collation in my.ini to utf8mb4_general_ci, but I am still getting undefined collation upon installation of some Joomla extensions.

```
default-character-set = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
character_set_server = utf8mb4
```

I know I can correct this by changing each record's collation individually, but that doesn't fix the undefined collations when I install a Joomla extension.

I noticed that some collations are utf8mb4_unicode_ci and some are utf8mb4_general_ci, so I don't think I should change the collation for all records.

Do these undefined collations have a negative impact on my site?

How do I fix this so the collation is not undefined during a new installation?

Comment: what the new and old versions of mysql?  note that in older versions, utf8 meant 3-byte utf8, which is more explicitly called utf8mb3 in new versions, and is deprecated.  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

Comment: what operating system/distribution does your server use?  what did you do to upgrade?  in some cases, you need to run a mysql_upgrade command after upgrading the software; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-what-is-upgraded.html

Comment: using Win7Ent.x64 with individual server software: apache2.4.54, MySQL8, php8.1.8, phpmyadmin 5.2.0.  Not a prebuilt stack. I created a new server folder, unzipped each software package into respective folders, copied httpd, my.ini, php.ini settings - line by line - to my new files after comparing differences in Notepad++ for each new file. I noticed php7_module is now just php_module, and DirectoryIndex requires " index.php# " when the # was not required previously. Also noticed utf8_general_ci is depracated, but some Joomla software still use it, thus the collation is undefined for those.

Comment: so the new version is some version of mysql 8?  what was the old version?

Comment: Prior versions:  apache 2.4.48, MySQL Server version: 8.0.18, php 7.4.1, phpadmin 5.1.1.  Current versions:  apache 2.4.54, MySQL Server version 8.0.29, php8.1.8, phpmyadmin 5.2.0

Comment: How does the undefined collation for those records affect the website? What would you do to resolve it? I'm quite sure each undefined record was previously using utf8_general_ci

Comment: I'm wondering if upgrading to the latest version of my server software is even worth the effort given the fact that most of the Joomla developers are still using the old utf8_general_ci collation that is deprecated in the latest MySQL and phpmyadmin. I've done a bunch of testing and it appears the utf8_general_ci is completely removed from the latest MySQL and phpmyadmin, so all tables with that collation get broken upon installation. It appears, based on the lack of help from this community, that I'm one of the first to discover this very irritating problem. DO NOT UPGRADE.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with MySQL server 8.0.29. I just upgraded to 8.0.31 and the problem is resolved.